# Pandas DataFrame mutability

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am pretty new to Panda's Dataframe and it would be highly appreciated if someone can briefly discuss about the mutability of DataFrame to me with the following example:

```
d1=pd.date_range('1/1/2016',periods=10,freq='w')
col1=['open','high','low','close']
list1=np.random.rand(10,4)
df1=pd.DataFrame(list1,d1,col1)
```

To my understanding, currently df1 is a reference to a df object.

If I pass df1 or slicing of df1 (e.g. `df1.iloc[2:3,1:2]`) as an input to a new df, (e.g. `df2=pd.DataFrame(df1)`), does df2 return a new instance of dataframe or it is still referring to df1 that makes df1 exposed to df2?

Also any other point that I should pay attention to regarding mutability of DataFrame will be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

This:

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame(df1)
```

Constructs a new DataFrame.  There is a `copy` parameter whose default argument is `False`.  According to the documentation, it means:

```
> Copy data from inputs. Only affects DataFrame / 2d ndarray input
```

So data will be shared between `df2` and `df1` by default.  If you want there to be no sharing, but rather a complete copy, do this:

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame(df1, copy=True)
```

Or more concisely and idiomatically:

```
df2 = df1.copy()
```

If you do this:

```
df2 = df1.iloc[2:3,1:2].copy()
```

You will again get an independent copy.  But if you do this:

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame(df1.iloc[2:3,1:2])
```

It will probably share the data, but this style is pretty unclear if you intend to modify `df`, so I suggest not writing such code.  Instead, if you want no copy, just say this:

```
df2 = df1.iloc[2:3,1:2]
```

In summary: if you want a reference to existing data, do not call `pd.DataFrame()` or any other method at all.  If you want an independent copy, call `.copy()`.

Comment: Thank you for your prompt answer. It seems like I should expect any slicing from a df to be mutable in general unless I apply a copy method. Am I conceptually correct?

On top of the slicing mentioned above, I realize that operations like .head() / .tail() by default returns a new instance of df that they are themselves immutable. I guess .head() / .tail() is free from mutability in this regard.

Comment: As a follow-up question about mutability of df in general, will the following assignment of part of a df (a column of it) to a new df create mutation issue?:
Say df1 is a DataFrame with columns including 'dummy'

`df2=pd.DataFrame(index=[1,2,3])  ` followed by

`df2['new dummy']=df1['dummy'] `

Is df1's 'dummy' column exposed to mutation?

Comment: @user7786493: No.

Answer (score 5):

> It will probably share the data, but this style is pretty unclear if you intend to modify df, so I suggest not writing such code. Instead, if you want no copy, just say this:
>
> ```
> df2 = df1.iloc[2:3,1:2]
> ```
>
> In summary: if you want a reference to existing data, do not call > pd.DataFrame() or any other method at all. If you want an independent copy, call .copy()

I do not agree. Doing the above would still return a reference to the sliced section of the original DataFrame. So, if you make any changes to df2, it will reflect in df1.

Rather the .copy() should be used,

```
df2 = df1.iloc[2:3,1:2].copy()
```

Comment: as a separate question that relates to slicing, it seems like index of a df/Series itself is an immutable object that slicing an index of a df/Series object returns a new object that don't mutate the original one, unlike the case of df.iloc.

e.g. In our last example, `df1.index[:]` actually returns a new instance/object rather than returns a reference. Am I correct?

Answer (score 2):

Great question, thanks. I ended up with playing around a bit after reading the other answers. So I want to share this with you.

**Here some code for playing around:**

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df=pd.DataFrame([[1,2,3],[4,5,6]])
print('start',df,sep='\n',end='\n\n')
def testAddCol(df):
    df=pd.DataFrame(df, copy=True) #experiment in this line: df=df.copy(), df=df.iloc[:2,:2], df.iloc[:2,:2].copy(), nothing, ...
    df['newCol']=11
    df.iloc[0,0]=100
    return df
df2=testAddCol(df)
print('df',df,sep='\n',end='\n\n')
print('df2',df2,sep='\n',end='\n\n')
```

**output:**

```
start
   0  1  2
0  1  2  3
1  4  5  6

df
   0  1  2
0  1  2  3
1  4  5  6

df2
     0  1  2  newCol
0  100  2  3      11
1    4  5  6      11
```